# My simple react native project won't render, any suggestions?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using the expo application on my phone to build a simple react native application, but I'm unable to render simple text. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import bball from './assets/bball.jpeg'

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    let pic = {
      uri: bball
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>hello, world</Text>
        <Image source={{pic}} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: There's no error message, that's what has me lost

Comment: If your statement says you cannot render text, then remove the image and render only the text. Plus check the debug tools, you should have some log somewhere

Comment: try to import image as import * as bball from './assets/bball.jpeg'
 and image component should accept either require if its static path or user uri if its uri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this way?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>hello, world</Text>
        <Image source={require('./assets/bball.jpeg')} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: @MyersNii-Ansah you're welcome! Mark as the correct one, so we can help other people that have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

**@Myers Nii-Ansah,** try to import image like

```
const image  = require('./my-icon.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

just use directly `bbal` in the source of image.

```
<Image source={bbal} />
```

if you have `url` of any image use like this.

```
<Image source={{uri: "https://example.com/image.png"}} />
```

so you can do this way if any how you can have image url from your component state.

```
render() {
    let pic = this.state.url ? { uri: this.state.url } : bbal
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>hello, world</Text>
        <Image source={pic} />
      </View>
    )
  }
```